# Firebase Proxy (reverse proxy)

Tags: firebase, proxy, reverse-proxy

I recently discovered [Netlify’s proxying feature](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/03/10/go-static-without-losing-your-server/), and it’s exactly the functionality I’m looking for. However, our team is heavily invested in **Firebase**, and adopting another provider is something higher-ups may not want to do.

My Netlify `_redirects` file looks like this

```
/ / 200
/* https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/:splat 200
```

So, is it possible to do a similar proxy with Firebase?
I want the base path `/` to route to `index.html`, but all other paths `/*` to proxy to another server `my-app.firebaseapp.com`.

I've tried using [Redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) and [Rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), but the former requires a `3xx` code and changes the url, and the later requires local files. I have a hunch the solution is to use Functions, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct -- to proxy traffic to arbitrary external URLs you will need to use the Firebase Hosting integration with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run). You can use e.g. [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) to forward requests, or manually construct the HTTP fetch and respond with the results.